# How to write a C/C++ wrapper program in Linux that is fully transparent

Tags: c, linux

Note: This is not a question to ask for a program, It asks about some tech details, see the question bellow first.

I need to write a wrapper program in C/C++ for an existing program. I know we need to use exec/fork/system and pass through the parameters then return the result of the program.

The question is, how to ensure that both the invoker program(that invoke the wrapper) and the wrapped program work exactly like before (ignore timing differences). There maybe subtle things like environment parameters to deal with. fork/system/exec, which to use? Are they enough? Are there other factors to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following original program:

*foo.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Called with: ${@}"
exit 23
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x foo.sh
```

Now the wrapper in `C`:

*wrapper.c*

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Executing wrapper code\n");

    /* do something ... */

    printf("Executing original program\n");
    if(execv("./foo.sh", argv) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to execute original program: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1; 
    }   
}
```

Run it:

```
$ gcc wrapper.c
$ ./a.out --foo -b "ar"
Executing wrapper code
Executing original program
Called with: --foo -b ar
$ echo $?
23
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the question clear, I need to use C/C++. Will execve make it fully transparent?

Comment: The simplest would be to use `execv()` because you don't want to modify the environment

Comment: Yes, it's fully transparent. Check `ps`; you won't even see the wrapper program.

Comment: I think you should return the result of execv to be transparent, right? p_invoker 's behavior may depends on the result of p_invoked.

Comment: I suddenly found that execv does't return the result of the invoked program, right? Then how can this be transparent?

Comment: execv replaces the current process with the child process. So in this example, the foo.sh script replaces the original C program. If you want to keep the C program running in parallel use fork to duplicate the process and run execv in the child.

Comment: @ Andrei Tumbar get it now, if exec successes, p_my vanishes and p_invoked begin to execute and return its result to p_invoker. Only shortcoming is that you can't do post-process although this is not my need here.

Comment: @jw_ You can do post process if you fork the c process and do waitpid() and wait for foo.sh to finish. This, however, leaves the original c program running if thats a problem.

Comment: Note that you don’t need to test the return value from any of the `exec*()` functions. If it succeeds, it doesn’t return; if it returns, it failed.