# Write a C/C++ fully transparent wrapper for a program that can't be renamed

Tags: c, linux, wrapper

I need to write a wrapper for AOSP prebuilt clang to do something when clang is invoked by the AOSP build script. The goal is rename clang to e.g. clang.original, and make a C/C++ wrapper that invoke clang.original then put it in the AOSP clang tool set folder and name it clang. For how to make a wrapper, reference: [How to write a wrapper program in Linux that is fully transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879376/how-to-write-a-wrapper-program-in-linux-that-is-fully-transparent)

But I found that the clang in AOSP is designed as if you rename it, it won't work any more.

Is there a way to make a wrapper for programs that can't be renamed?

Or at least is there a way to work around about the prebuilt clang?

For reference:

The size of the prebuilt clang is just 6.4KB, there is a 60MB clang-6.0. So this clang itself is a wrapper of the real clang-6.0. The build script will invoke clang. I rename clang to clang.original. Even when you run directly "./clang.original" in bash, there is error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last) :
File "./clang.original", line 174, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File "./clang.original", line 170, in main
cw.invoke_compiler()
File "./clang.original", line 144, in invoke_compiler
os.execv(self.argv0, self.execargs)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why do you need to rename it?  Why not preserve its name but put it in a different directory?

Comment: @ jamesdlin this doesn't work, too. I've tried to put both clang and clang-6.0 to another folder, still get the above error. Updated: if I modify the folder name directly, it works, so my failure may due to that clang need more than clang-6.0

Comment: Wait, the "No such file or directory" error you're getting is trying to invoke clang.  That error is from *your* program.  Are you sure your program is getting the correct path to `clang`?

Comment: @ jamesdlin To isolate the error, the above error has nothing to do with my program, I invoke the renamed clang from bash.

Comment: That you can invoke `clang` from bash doesn't isolate the error.  If you actually want to isolate your error, the you should verify that your program can execute other programs and that its current working directory is what you think it is.

Comment: @ jamesdlin Update: rename/copy the folder to the same level is ok. Move/Copy it to another level trigger other errors. But I think copy the folder(i.e. ***/bin) will trigger other problems during build which is a very complex process.

Comment: @ jamesdlin "That error is from your program" I didn't run my program, how can the error is from my program? The error is from clang.original which I invoked directly from bash.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  So to be clear: you renamed the Python *wrapper* script, and the wrapper script fails?  If you want to intercept invocations to the actual `clang-6.0` binary, then why not rename *that* and insert your wrapper as `clang-6.0`?

Comment: The error message you posted is clearly a Python exception, which is why I was confused.  I don't have any problems running an actual `clang` binary when renamed, so the problem is solely in the wrapper script.  You also could just modify the wrapper script directly.

Comment: @ jamesdlin yes, I found that too. But even so I didn't realize I can just wrap clang-6.0(stupid...), get in between clang and clang-6.0 as you said, there is no need to edit the script. Wrapping clang-6.0 is the right answer to the clang work around question.